# OneSignal Mobile Push notification: Action buttons are not showing until long press it

Tags: react-native, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

For my react-native project, I am using Onesignal api to send notifications to users with action buttons Yes & No.

When I receive notification it shows action buttons only when long press the notification.

As shown below: 
When I receive it looks like this:

[image]

If I long press the notification then only it shows action buttons: 
[image]

This is how I send notification with action buttons.

```
 {
                contents: {
                    en: "Are you coming to work today?"
                },
                app_id: OneSignalAppID,
                // included_segments: ["Subscribed Users"],
                include_player_ids: [...],
                priority: 10,
                buttons: [{
                    id: "yes-feedback", text: "Yes"
                },
                { id: "no-feedback", text: "No" }
                ]

            },
```

I Have tried to look on how to make custom buttons but could not find anything yet. 
Also I have seen some apps' notifications shows button popped out already without pressing it so its probably doable but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you know this by now, but that is standard behavior for iOS. The notification action buttons only show up if you long press or "view" the notification. Good Luck!